# Add or delete row depending on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my Excel worksheet (modified with Worksheet_Change functionality) inserts or delete new rows depending on the numeric value of another cell.

For example, as the image shows, if I introduce the value "7", Excel inserts 6 new rows under row 5 (the minimum value in B2 would be 1):

[image]

The code I have so far can add the number of rows but, if I make changes and introduce a smaller value, it does not delete the rows left:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:E500")) Is Nothing Then
Call Macro1
End If
```

---

```
Sub Macro1()   
NDay = Range("B2").Value
    
    For i = 1 To NSesion - 1
    
      Range("A6").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFromrightorabove
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You said "insert or delete". Can you explain how it deletes? (do you enter negative numbers?)

Comment: If I have introduce 7, my Excel code will introduce 6 new rows. But, if just after, I introduce 2, I would only need 2 rows, so Excel should delete the 5 rows left.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `NSesion` in Macro1 is not declared and has no value. Use `Option Explicit` at the very top of the code window to catch errors like these.

The code has other issues. The first sub has no end sub. It runs whenever ANY cell in range A1 to E500 is changed. Do you want that? Or do you only want it to run when a number is changed in B2? Also, the code will create an endless loop, since you are changing (inserting rows) cells in the range that is watched by the change event.

The code below only runs when cell B2 is changed. It will first delete rows 6 to 11, then insert rows and enter incrementing numbers into column B. Let me know if that works for you.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    Call Macro1
End If
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
Dim NDay As Long, i As Long
NDay = Range("B2").Value
    
    Range("A6:A11").EntireRow.Delete
    For i = 1 To NDay - 1
        Range("A" & 5 + i).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range("B" & 5 + i) = i + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that there are more elegant ways to write this, but I built upon your approach to help you understand what went wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you, @teylyn, but I am facing another issue: There is important information below the table, and this code deletes rows in a static way with "Range("A6:A11").EntireRow.Delete". Is there any way that it deletes dynamically the number of rows I introduced before?. Another approach: if I introduce the value "20", 9 rows won't be deleted as the code only reaches number "11".

Comment: You have the structure. Now just use different commands. If you insert whole rows, they will upset the structure, too. The macro will not know how many rows you inserted last time. Use ClearContents instead of deleting rows. then don't insert rows, just relabel them.

Comment: Add `Dim lastRow as long`. Replace the line `Range("A6:A11")...` with these lines `lastRow = Range("A4").Last(xlDown).Row`, `If lastRow > 5 and lastRow - 4 <> NDay then`, `Range("A6:A" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete`, `End if`. This is not tested but easily debuggable.